# Vue using .length on array not working in style

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
<div
      v-for="(item, index) in data.items"
      :style="'display:inline-block !important; padding-left: 2% !important; padding-right: 2% !important; width: ' + data.items.length + '% !important'"
      :key="index">
```

The `width: ' + data.items.length + '%`Part is not rendering. It is not displayed in the html. When I replace it with `width: ' + 10 + '%` it is working.

Is .length not working in Vue? I thought it was?

Script tag:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    jsonData: {
      type: String,
      default: "{}"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    data: function() {
      return JSON.parse(this.jsonData);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Show your Script Tag pls (the part of the items)

Comment: More than likely, you're looking at the result in the debugger, not the raw value(s). I would guess that something in your syntax is resulting in invalid styling syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div >
      <div v-for="(item, index) in data.items"
        :style="{display:'inline-block !important', paddingLeft: '2% !important',
          paddingRight:'2% !important',
          width:'data.items.length +'%' !important'}">
      </div>
      </div>
---
data () {
    return {
      data:{
        items: ["x","y","z"]
      }

    }


width comes 3%
```